# Vuetify : how to change items-per-page select items in v-data-table component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In data table component footer , there is select option that i need to change its numbers

How can I do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be applied to v-data-footer, but if you want to apply that to v-data-table, the items per page can be set in that way:

```
<v-data-table
     :footer-props="{'items-per-page-options':[15, 30, 50, 100, -1]}"
 ...>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with vuetify 3.x any more (trying 3.2.2). Yes, I know, it's still in Lab stage. Still, anybody know?

Answer (score 2):

Take alook at following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),

data () {
      return {
        opts:[3,7,8,13,17,-1],
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
          { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 375,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,
            protein: 0.0,
            iron: '0%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 392,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,
            protein: 0,
            iron: '2%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 408,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,
            protein: 6.5,
            iron: '45%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 452,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,
            protein: 4.9,
            iron: '22%',
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 518,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,
            protein: 7,
            iron: '6%',
          },
        ],
      }
    },
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="desserts"
          :items-per-page="5"
          class="elevation-1"
          :footer-props="{'items-per-page-options':opts}"
        >
        </v-data-table>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vuetify 3.X

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  :items-per-page-options="[
    { value: 10, title: '10' },
    { value: 20, title: '20' },
    { value: 30, title: '30' }
  ]"
/>
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-items-per-page